# matplotlib: dynamically change text position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to **display some text next to the cursor** as it moves through a plot generated by matplotlib.

I know how to get the mouse motion events, but how do I **change the position of the text** element **dynamically**?

The following code shows how to position a line depending on the position of the cursor:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line = ax.plot([0, 1], [0,1])[0]

def on_mouse_move(event):
    if None not in (event.xdata, event.ydata):
        # draws a line from the center (0, 0) to the current cursor position
        line.set_data([0, event.xdata], [0, event.ydata])
        fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_mouse_move)
plt.show()
```

How can I do something similar with text? I've tried `text.set_data` but that didn't work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446307/update-annotations-in-matplotlib-using-buttons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the solution being as simple as **`text.set_position((x, y))`**.

See the following example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
text = ax.text(1, 1, 'Text')

def on_mouse_move(event):
    if None not in (event.xdata, event.ydata):
        text.set_position((event.xdata, event.ydata))
        fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_mouse_move)
plt.show()
```